# Https Security Integration with Camunda BPM

Tags: spring-security, camunda

I have used ldap based camunda-auth to login to the application using HttpBasicAuthenticationProvider provided by camunda, where how can I implement https login and is it supported by camunda (or) we need to use spring security? 
Please send any link related or config to camunda - https implementation.

Comment: What do you mean by https login? If you mean basic authentication over https, that would be something to configure e.g. in tomcat to force connections to use https.

Comment: yes, using https authentication using tomcat, but I need to know how to configure ldap based authentication to authentication provider in camunda  for secured connection.

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me whether you want to secure the connection between user and camunda app or between camunda and ldap. See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service/#the-ldap-identity-service for the camunda specific ldap configuration, to use a secure connection to ldap I think you just have to specify the `ldaps` protocol and the correct port to use ssl encrypted connections.

Comment: Hi @user3428736 were able to implement this. Could you provide any insights ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you correctly- you want to set up camunda to have TLS and additionally you want LDAP authorization? 
To set up TLS, you need to configure it directly on Tomcat server.
First you need to obtain/generate certificates.
Then you need to point to those certificates in server.xml configuration file.
Just google "TLS on Tomcat". I'm sure there are hundreds of tutorials how to do this step by step.

When it comes to LDAP integration - follow documentation:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/installation/full/tomcat/configuration/#ldap